# In environment ice freezes from top to bottom but in refrigirator it seems to be opposite i.e from bottom then top then middle part. Why?

Tags: thermodynamics

Water should have to start freezing from top but everytime I open my refrigirator I always saw water above ice, then small layer of ice (in mid some water).

Comment: It depends on the design of the elements conducting the refrigerator cooling fluid, rather than how we think of how a lake freezes over  from the top.

Comment: Remember that the bottom of the lake is (generally) above freezing, at least until the lake has frozen solid.

Answer (score 1):

In nature, the cold air is above the water, but in a refrigerator, the cold air is all around the water. The part of the water that is closest to the cold air always freezes first. So a lake will freeze from the top down, but a bottle of water in a fridge will freeze from the outside in (assuming it is cold enough to freeze at all).

If only part of your refrigerator is cold enough to freeze water, then the water you put near that part will freeze first.

Comment: Cool answer :) I have to attack my fridge every month to clear the icebox.

Answer (score 0):

Temperature changes occur due to the flow of heat (aka energy). And heat tends to flow along the path of least thermal resistance. So for the lake, that path is to the air. And in the freezer,  it's at the base of the ice tray.